# transfer files from windows to linux?

Tags: c#, wpf, linux, plink

I'm trying to connect to a linux machine via pLink and PuTTY to transfer some .txt file. Right now I'm just trying to make the connection work. I have a small window with 2 textboxes (username,linux1) and a password box (pwbox1), and a button that when you click, it should connect you to the linux machine!

Here's my code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string user = username.Text;
        string passw = pwbox1.Password;
        string linuxHst = linux1.Text;

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe", user + "@" + linuxHst + " -pw " + passw);

        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
        Process process = Process.Start(psi);
        process.WaitForExit(5000);
    }
```

The problem is that when I try this with the console application it works, without the textboxes! but I need it to work with WPF. 
Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly is not working as you expect, and what do you observe instead? "But i need it to work with WPF" is not really a problem description...

Comment: it doesn't show that I'm connected to the linux machine! the cmd window is empty! it should show something like "using mowglin..", shouldn't it?

Comment: Why should the cmd window show anything if you do `psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;`? If you don't want to redirect the console output and see it in its cmd window, don't redirect it ;) (A similar argument might perhaps apply to `psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;` - not sure if you need/want to do keyboard input in this cmd window)

Comment: but the exact same code works with the console application! and it shows that I'm connected.

Comment: Well, if it works in the console application then the code you execute there in your console application is *not* exactly the same as depicted above... -- there you might have some code lines that make it kinda work (perhaps something like `Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());`)